# HAML Ruby - making a table with unknown # of columns with key value pairs

Tags: ruby, haml

```
- oldpid = []
- @res.each do |r|
    - if r[:pid] != oldpid
        - oldpid = r[:pid]
        %tr
            %td= r[:pid]
            %td= r[:bc]
            - else
            %td= r[:bc]
```

I don't know how many columns I will have in a table.  I get a list with a 'pid' and a 'bc' and if the 'pid' matches the previous one, I want to add it in the same row.  I have tried indenting the else statement all sorts of ways, but this is the closest.  This will put two 'bc's in a row, but put the third one on a new line.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Other attempts work, but all of them put an extra <tr></tr> in between lines and that is undesirable

Comment: Just looks like that else statement is way out. It should be exactly at the same column in the text as the latest if.

Comment: You have key/value pairs, so why can't you use the keys to tell you how many columns you have? We need to see samples of the data you're working with if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Id go with a `group_by`. Let me assume your data:

```
@res = [{pid: 2, bc: 'DATA1'},
        {pid: 3, bc: 'DATA2'},
        {pid: 2, bc: 'DATA3'},
        {pid: 4, bc: 'DATA4'},
        {pid: 2, bc: 'DATA5'}]

@res.group_by { |e| e[:pid] }
=> {2 => [{:pid=>2, :bc=>"DATA1"},
          {:pid=>2, :bc=>"DATA3"},
          {:pid=>2, :bc=>"DATA5"}],
    3 => [{:pid=>3, :bc=>"DATA2"}],
    4 => [{:pid=>4, :bc=>"DATA4"}]}
```

So...

```
- @res.group_by { |e| e[:pid] }.each do |pid, elements|
  %tr
    %td= pid
    %td= elements.join # ?
```

I'm not sure what are you trying to do, but you should be just a few hacks away from here.

Comment: Formatting the data before HAML gets it was the way to go and group_by worked like a charm.  I think the elements.join would need the separator as html to keep the table structure I wanted, so I looped through elements instead of mixing HAML and html.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your data looks like this:

```
@res = [{ pid: 1, bc: 4 }, { pid: 1, bc: 3 }, { pid: 2, bc: 6 }, { pid: 3, bc: 8 }]
```

You could convert it into a handier structure like this...

```
res_hash = @res.inject({}) { |h, pair| (h[pair[:pid]] ||= []) << pair[:bc]; h }
=> { 1: [4, 3], 2: [6], 3: [8] }
```

Now your HAML (if I understand your requirements correctly) is a lot easier:

```
- res_hash.each |k, v|
  %tr
    %td= k
    - v.each |bc|
      %td= bc
```

(This outputs a cell for the value of :pid followed by a cell for every :bc value for that key)

Comment: You are right on.  I ended up using group_by just because I had some more data than I showed (and it seemed easier to me).

Comment: Yeah, group_by is a reasonable solution then.